# "Esami" package: random extraction from a set of elements?

Tags: random-numbers, random, esami

I am trying to give randomness to a test with the "esami" package and the command "randestrai" was promising. I wanted to pick some random prime numbers so I wrote

```
\randestrai{3,5,7,11}{alpha}
```

which generates the variables `\alphai`, `\alphaii`... by picking randomly their values from the set {3,5,7,11}. Then I used these variables as parameters in the exercises but something is going wrong because the values of each `\alphai` is always the same for every version of the test so the randomization seems useless. What am I doing/understanding wrong?

Comment: We are not able to reproduce the problem you have, as with the example files everithing works as expected.
Can you please post a MWE or at least your master file and the exercise file, so that we can try them and see the problem? Which version of the `esami` package are you using?